# NestJS - Unauthorized on callback

Tags: javascript, typescript, api, oauth-2.0

I want to create an authorization via Github to my app, and after successfull authorization save my `access_token` to databse of the current logged-in to the system user, but i have a problem with authorization on `GET` to my `callback` :(

after click on button in my vue.js app:

```
<a href="https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize?client_id=SOME_CLIENT_ID&scope=repo/">
    <b-button variant="danger" style="height:38px;" class="ml-1">
        Connect
    </b-button>
</a>
```

I'm properly redirect to github authentication page. In settings of my Github App I set my `callback` to endpoint where my function (in `nestjs` server) listen, here is controller and function from service:

controller

```
    @Get('github-callback')
    @AuthRequired()
    async githubCallback( @Req() req: Request, @Res() res: Response, @CurrentUser() user: User): Promise<void> {
      return await this.authService.githubAuthAccessToken(req, res, user);
    }
```

service
in this two method, in first I get an `access_token` from response of the callback, in the second(reference to first), I get data of my user and update user `access_token` in databse:

```
async githubAuthAccessToken(req: Request, res: Response, user: User): Promise<void> {
    console.log("user: " + user);
    let token;

    const body = {
      client_id: process.env.GITHUB_CLIENT_ID,
      client_secret: process.env.GITHUB_CLIENT_SECRET,
      code: req.query.code
    };
    const opts = { headers: { accept: 'application/json' }};
    const response = await axios.post(`https://github.com/login/oauth/access_token`, body, opts);
    token = response.data.access_token;

    console.log(response.data);

    await this.getGithubUserData(token, user);

    res.redirect('http://localhost:8080/github');
  }

  async getGithubUserData(accessToken: string, user: User): Promise<void> {
    const response = await axios.get('https://api.github.com/user', {
      headers: {
        authorization : `token ${accessToken}`,
        'X-OAuth-Scopes': 'repo, user',
        'X-Accepted-OAuth-Scopes': 'repo, user'
      }
    });

    await this.userService.updateGithubToken(accessToken, response.data.login, user);
  }
```

After click on my button in `vuejs` app I'm redirecting to github auth page, and after click on `authorize` instead of redirecting to `http://localhost:8080/github`, my server return me `Unathorized` :(

can anybody tell me why I'm unathorize to my server when I `GET` on my callback? (I need to be authorize because i need to update user object), Can anybody help me? Thanks fot any help!

Comment: Obviously nestjs throws an ```UnauthorizedException()```. I don't see you throw this exception, so my best guess is that ```AuthRequired()``` may be the reason.